# Link two tables with a one-to-one relationship, using the same unique key

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables that need to be linked one to one by the key field email.
When I try to do this, I get an error like this:

*Cannot use table 'UserSettings' for entity type 'UserSettings' since it is being used for entity type 'UserSettings' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'UserSettings' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'UserSettings'.*

how I tried to implement it:

```
public class UserSettingsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserSettings>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserSettings> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(n => n.Email);

        builder.HasOne(n => n.User)
            .WithOne(u => u.UserSettings)
            .HasForeignKey<UserSettings>(k => k.Email)
            .HasPrincipalKey<UserSettings>(k => k.Email);
    }
}
```

UserSettings and User entities:

```
public class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public UserSettings UserSettings { get; set; }
}

public class UserSettings
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code instead of screenshots. Also the `User` configuration.

Comment: public UserSettings should probably be Virtual... so public virtual UserSettings... Email doesn't seem like a primary key...  really it seems like you should just put everything in "User" table.  Why make a 2nd?

Comment: `UserSettings` cannot be both **principal** and **dependent** of the same relationship. Assuming it is the dependent (from `.HasForeignKey<UserSettings>(k => k.Email)` call), then `.HasPrincipalKey<UserSettings>(k => k.Email)` is wrong - must be `.HasPrincipalKey<User>(k => k.Email)`.